# Salesforce Long Text Area fields in formulas

Tags: formula

Im using Professional Edition.Is there anyway to use long text area in formulas. Im searched most of the links but i didn't get any answer. Please tell me how to resolve the issues.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

No, there is not. There is an Idea to support it [here](https://success.salesforce.com/ideaView?id=08730000000BrhE). In the comments for that Idea, there is a workaround described (and also linked to and described [here](http://linkingto.blogspot.de/2011/08/salesforce-long-text-area-and-formulas.html)) that uses workflow, but that isn't available in PE. I can't think of a way to do it in PE without an API integration, which requires PE API access enabled at additional cost.