# Is there a formula I can use to count the occurrence of a word in a string?

Tags: formula-field, string

What I'm trying to do is to have a formula on a record, that counts the occurrences of a specific word from within a string field on the same record that holds a paragraph of text.

If for example someone wrote in the text field: "Isn't my dog amazing! I love my dog!" .. where now an adjacent Formula field [Occurrence of word "dog"] would derive the number 2..

Is there a way to do this without Apex?

Comment: Formulas support regex, which can be used to achieve your requirement

Comment: @BrianMansfield would you mind elaborating on how a regex formula can count matches along with a working example?

Comment: @MarkPond the fact that someone as reputable as you commented makes me inclined to think that it's probably not possible :P but i'll take a stab at it and see

Comment: @MarkPond I was wrong, you could enforce the number of times a known word appeared in the string with a regular expression, but I don't think you can count the number of occurrences. Sorry for the mistake Mikhail!

Comment: Could you give a more specific example of your requirement? Is this a text area field that you want to count the number of occurrences of a specific word, not just validate that it exists and/or repeats a min/max number of times?

Comment: Well first of all, you cannot reference Long Text Areas in formulas ([http://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/12919/salesforce-long-text-area-fields-in-formulas](http://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/12919/salesforce-long-text-area-fields-in-formulas))
So is it a field of type "Text Area (Long)" or just "Text Area" ?

Comment: @crmprogdev - My requirement is to just count the amount of times a word appears in a sentence.  ie:  "Isn't my dog amazing? I love my dog!"  :: count of occurrence of the word dog = 2, and if it ever changes to be automatically updated.

Comment: @JulienGaïotto - thank you for that, I can use the Text Area field instead of the Text Area (Long) for my needs, but you saved me figuring that out the hard way.

Thank you :)

Comment: It has occurred to me that I will know the length of the words I'm looking for.  So would it be possible to continuously count the occurrence of a word, if I was to have a formula that does something like the following, for the word "dog"?

(LEN(Text Area) - LEN(SUBSTITUTE(Text Area,"dog","")))/3

(ps: I'm not worried about case sensitivity)

Comment: Does the count matter if ultimately what you want to do is be able to replace the word? Or, is a change in the count what you want to use to "trigger" a replacement of the word? Your use case would be helpful to know in order to fully understand your requirements.

Comment: I still don't get if you want a specific word like "dog" or just the the word with the most occurences?

Comment: @crmprogdev - I'm only looking for the COUNT of occurrences of the word, not to replace it or do any kind of change to the original text.

Comment: @FrederikWitte - I am not looking for the word with the most occurrences, I am looking for a count of occurrences of a specific word.

Answer (score 6):

Ok, so it seems to be that this is possible, but within limits, such as that your text field cannot be of the (Long) type, and must be a regular Text Area field, thus limiting the text entry field to 255 characters, and you need to know the length of the word you're looking for. (And remember to mitigate for case sensitivity by using LOWER.)

Such as, if you wish to count the occurrence of the word "dog" (a 3 character word) in your 255 character (Text Area) field, it would look like this:

```
(LEN(Text Area) - LEN(SUBSTITUTE(LOWER(Text Area),"dog","")))/3
```

*Special thanks to Julien Gaïotto for contributing.

Answer (score 3):

That is actually a good idea to do that.

[Salesforce documentation](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.pages.meta/pages/pages_variables_functions.htm) does not say if the SUBSTITUTE function is case sensitive or not... :( whereas BEGINS or CONTAINS are.

But if you're worried about case sensitivity, juste use

```
SUBSTITUTE(LOWER(Text Area),"dog","")
```

Comment: Thank you.  Using LOWER will solve the last bit of reliability in the formula :)

It does unfortunately state that "SUBSTITUTE" is case sensitive though, in the documentation here:  https://help.salesforce.com/apex/HTViewHelpDoc?id=customize_functions_i_z.htm&language=en_US#SUBSTITUTE